# Android - Not updating GUI onResume

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout

I have a class called HeaderView which I use all over my application:

```
public HeaderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    ctx = context;

    commonApi = AAALifestyleApplication.commonApi;
    user = commonApi.getCurrentUser();

    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_view, this, true);

    ((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.logo)).setOnClickListener(this);

    inboxButton = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.inbox_image);
    inboxButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    inboxButton2 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.inbox_image2);
    inboxButton2.setOnClickListener(this);

    requestsButton = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.requests_image);
    requestsButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    requestsButton2 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.requests_image2);
    requestsButton2.setOnClickListener(this);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) this.findViewById(R.id.header_progress_bar);
    if (!showProgressBar) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    }
    AAAAsyncTask.setProgressBarListener(this);

    refreshView();
}

public static void refreshView(){
    SharedPreferences sp = ctx.getSharedPreferences("HeaderView", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int newMessages = sp.getInt("newMessagesCount", 0);
    int newRequests = sp.getInt("newRequestsCount", 0);
    if(newMessages > 0){
        Log.d("daim", "new messages!");
        inboxButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        inboxButton2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        Log.d("daim", "no new messages!");
        inboxButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        inboxButton2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if(newRequests > 0){
        requestsButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        requestsButton2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        requestsButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        requestsButton2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

In my Activity, this HeaderView gets called onCreate cause its specified in the XML, and also in onResume() like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    HeaderView.refreshView();
}
```

In the onCreate() method this works correctly, but onResume() I get the right amount of messages and I even logged this, so I know for sure that "no new messages" is printed, but the setVisibility() method doesn't update at all, and instead I see the previous ImageView when I had "new messages".

Please help, I've tried using handler with a thread to see if that was the problem, but it still remains this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should instantiate your view, and make the `refreshView` non-static.

Declare your `Activity` like this:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    private HeaderView mHeaderView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mHeaderView = new HeaderView(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        mHeaderView.refreshView();
    }
}
```

And remove the `static` keyword in your `refreshView` method declaration.

Comment: I have HeaderView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs): I cannot do headerView = new HeaderView(this)?

Comment: I implemented a HeaderView(Context) also and followed your steps, but it still doesn't work!?

Comment: Than make a second Constructor with context only. If you automtaically generate the Constructors via "Right click - Source - Create Constructor from superclass" Eclipse will automatically generate all possible (and needed) constructors.

Comment: I tried this, the method gets called but it doesn't update the view. I changed it to non-static.

Comment: I managed this by using headerView = (HeaderView) findViewById(R.id.header); and then did an invalidate in the onResume(). I'll accept your answer for pointing me to the right direction though.